# Android | Kotlin: How to make RecyclerView itemClick from Firebase Cloud Firestore?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to make my RecyclerView item clickable, and after that show in DetailsActivity. I have made my code like this to show Toast and Log, but no data is showing. Is there something wrong with my code? Or is something missing? I have searched Google and YouTube a lot that should use Firestore Adapter. Is that so? If yes, I don't know how to use this Firestore Adapter.

This is code for **OutletAdapter.kt**

```
class OutletAdapter(private val context: Context, private val outletList: MutableList<Outlet>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<OutletAdapter.OutletViewHolder>() {

    private lateinit var itemOutletBuyerBinding: ItemOutletBuyerBinding

    private var onItemClickListener: OnItemClickListener? = null

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): OutletViewHolder {
        itemOutletBuyerBinding = ItemOutletBuyerBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)

        return OutletViewHolder(itemOutletBuyerBinding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: OutletViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(outletList[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return outletList.size
    }

    fun setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener: OnItemClickListener?) {
        this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener
    }

    inner class OutletViewHolder(private val itemOutletBuyerBinding: ItemOutletBuyerBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemOutletBuyerBinding.root) {

        fun bind(outlet: Outlet) {
            with(itemOutletBuyerBinding) {

                    ... -> View Binding

                }
            }

            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                onItemClickListener?.onItemClicked(outlet)
            }
        }

    }

    interface OnItemClickListener {
        fun onItemClicked(data: Outlet)
    }

}
```

This is code for **Fragment.kt**

```
rvExploreBuyerOutlet.apply {
    layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(requireActivity(), 2)
    setHasFixedSize(true)

    firebaseFirestore.collection("outlets").get().apply {
        addOnSuccessListener { querySnapshot ->
                    
            ...

            querySnapshot.toObjects(Outlet::class.java).also { outletData ->
                outletList.apply {
                    for (i in 0 until outletData.size / 2) {
                        add(outletData[i])
                        add(outletData[i + outletData.size / 2])
                    }

                    for (i in 0 until size / 2) {
                        when {
                            i % 2 == 0 -> {
                                val temp = this[i]

                                this[i] = this[size - 2 - i]
                                this[size - 2 - i] = temp
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    for (document in this) {
                        outletAdapter = OutletAdapter(requireActivity(), this as ArrayList<Outlet>)
                    }
                }
            }

            adapter = outletAdapter

            outletAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(object : OutletAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
                override fun onItemClicked(data: Outlet) {
                    Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Item ${data.outletNumber}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    Log.d("itemClicked", data.toString())
                }
            })

            adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this task more simply.

1. Remove the interface.
2. Add a **lambda** function to the primary constructor.
3. Rewrite the `bind` function

```kotlin
class OutletAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    private val outletList: MutableList<Outlet>
    private val onItemClickListener: (Outlet) -> Unit = {}
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<OutletAdapter.OutletViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): OutletViewHolder {
        val itemOutletBuyerBinding = ItemOutletBuyerBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), 
            parent, 
            false
        )
        return OutletViewHolder(itemOutletBuyerBinding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: OutletViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(outletList[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = outletList.size

    inner class OutletViewHolder(
        private val itemOutletBuyerBinding: ItemOutletBuyerBinding
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemOutletBuyerBinding.root) {

        fun bind(outlet: Outlet) {
            with(itemOutletBuyerBinding) {
                ... -> View Binding
                root.setOnClickListener {
                    onItemClickListener(outlet)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```kotlin
outletAdapter = OutletAdapter(requireContext(), outletList) { data ->
    Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Item ${data.outletNumber}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    Log.d("itemClicked", data.toString())
}
```

The lambda function is passed to the adapter and it is fired whenever the layout has been clicked.

Comment: wow! thanks for the simplified code, I will use it now. But, my recyclerview item is still not clickable and also no response from Toast or Log.

Comment: Was the recyclerview item still unclickable with the original code?